# Ryanair Random Seating

Tags: statistics

This is in response to this news [article](https://soylentnews.org/article.pl?sid=17/07/02/1223240). Relevant quote:

> Dr Rogers, calculated the chances of all four people being randomly given middle seats on each of the flights, to be around 1:540,000,000

This does not even close to pass the sniff test. She is stating that after running 4 trials, each trial just slightly more rigorous than a coin flip, that her confidence in the non-randomness of the answer is 99.9999998%

When I try to work out the statistics myself I get.

Four independent events, assuming that we start with airline with 0 reserved seats (or reserved seats that were uniformly reserved across aisle , window, and middle)

```
1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3
= (1/3)^4
= 1/81
Or a 1:81 chance. A 7 million percent difference from what Rogers found.

Standard Deviation = sqrt(sum(difference from mean)^2/num_trials)
= sqrt((((2/3) squared) * 3)/4)
= 0.58
With a .57 confidence interval for a 95% confidence level.
1 +or- .6
```

So the interesting part is that I sort of confirmed Roger's results. Their is a 95% chance that the results were non-random, as our 95% confidence interval does not include 1/3, it gets fairly close but it seems 4 trials really are enough to prove the non-random aspect of the seating.

Did I calculate the relevant statics correctly?
How did the "Director of the new Oxford University Statistical Consultancy" find  the nonsensical 1:540,000,000 number?

Comment: On that news article page, there is a comment that states: `"Allocated randomly" does not mean that the results are necessarily uniformly distributed.` That seems to be the salient point. The airline would presumably be randomly allocating seats to people who do not wish to pay more, presumably from the set of middle seats (or to fill in gaps) ... so that they can keep the aisle and window seats free for passengers who wish to pay more, or who want 3 seats in a row or some such other conditions. It may still be a random allocation with non-Uniform sampling.

Comment: You left out the most important part of the quote: "**By looking at the amount of window, aisle and middle seating available on each flight, at the time of check-in**, Dr Rogers, calculated the chances...". We don't have this information, but if for example there was 337 seats available and only 4 of them was middle seats then you would get this answer assuming a uniform distribution.

Comment: Notice that your "CI" $1 \pm .6$ extends beyond the interval $(0,1)$ permissible for probabilities.

Comment: @BruceET Yes, I am not sure if that effects the statistics or the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have four independent Bernoulli trials, each resulting in Tails,
then the assumptions for the confidence interval (CI) you give are not met.
Some statisticians feel that there are philosophical issues in making
a CI based on small numbers of Bernoulli trials all with the same
outcome. Perhaps a Bayesian approach would work better.

If you begin with the prior view that $\theta = P(Tail)$ is roughly
around 1/3, you might use the prior distribution 
$\theta \sim \mathsf{Beta}(1,2)$ so that $E(\theta) = 1/3$ and
$P(\theta < 2/3) \approx 0.89$ (as computed using R statistical software).

```
pbeta(2/3, 1, 2)
#[1] 0.8888889
```

Then a Bayesian probability interval for $\theta$ based on four
Middle seats (Tails) among four subjects, would be based on the posterior
distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(5, 2)$. Specifically, a 95% probability
interval would be $(0.36, 0.96),$ which does not include 1/3.

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 5, 2)
#[1] 0.3587654 0.9567281
```

*Notes:* (a) This result is obtained by multiplying the prior kernel (density function
without constant of integration) $\theta^{1-1}(1-\theta)^{2-1}$ by the
conjugate likelihood function $\theta^4(1-\theta)^0$ to get the beta
posterior kernel $\theta^{5-1}(1-\theta)^{2-1},$ which corresponds
to $\mathsf{Beta}(5,2).$

(b) However, as Commented by @Wolfies, it is possible that the airline's PR materials, about the 'random' seating of passengers who do not pay extra
extra to avoid middle seats, may not be totally transparent.

(c) If the 'expert' had just endured a flight on an airline that emphasizes
low fares above customer satisfaction, one might understand the reason for an illogical
computation. Perhaps the capacity for rational thought might return after
a few days on the ground.